# local changes in expo app affecting the google downloaded app without updating the app in google play or app store

Tags: react-native, expo

I am doing the changes in my local machine in react native expo app. but after the build,  the changes are reflecting in the app I downloaded from the google play without update the app on google play. I don't why this is happening. is it expo natural behaver or I did something, that I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Expo, by default, supports Over the Air (OTA) updates which pushes a new JS bundle to live apps when you publish.

You can disable this by changing your app.json to include:

```
{
    "updates": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

For more information on configuring OTA updates see the [Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/#updates)